# Does Ubuntu use Intel SGX?

Tags: boot

My Lenovo computer offers SGX as an option in the BIOS menu. I am wondering if I should enable it on my on my Ubuntu 22.04 system.

Does Ubuntu utilize Intel's SGX feature?

Should I enable SGX for my Ubuntu system?

Comment: if your question has been answered, please go ahead and close out this topic so it doesn't remain in the Unasnwered Questions queue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, Ubuntu can make use of SGX if it's enabled.

To answer your second question (more important, IMHO), there's a bit more to consider regarding why you'd want to make use of SGX service offerings. So the answer is "it depends." For some context, here's a quote from the [Wikipedia entry on SGX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Guard_Extensions) that suggests that SGX may no longer be of value to the typical user:

> A pivot by Intel in 2021 resulted in the deprecation of SGX from the
> 11th and 12th generation Intel Core Processors, but development
> continues on Intel Xeon for cloud and enterprise use

So, the determining factor for whether to enable SGX will depend on your particular use case (for my own development work, my machines do not have SGX enabled). There's plenty of online debate on this topic, and I'd urge you to read and make your own decision.