# x86/cpu: SGX disable by BIOS

Tags: bios, sgx

I recently tried to install Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) next to Windows 10 already on my main PC, and then after doing some operations, when starting from a bootable USB flash drive, an error occurs (x86/cpu: SGX disable by BIOS).

I tried to do something for two days, but it didn't work out for me. I did not find this setting in the BIOS (the latest BIOS version is 2023), I tried to download the activator from Intel - it gives an error there (We can't activate Intel ® SGX from this App), I tried to download the sgx sdk for Windows myself, they also give errors(This platform is not Intel ® SGX-compatible. Please check your Intel ® SGX BIOS settings. Install will cancel. \ The installed version of Windows is not supported by this installer. If you enable Intel ® SGX on your system, Windows Update install Intel ® SGX Platform Software automatically.).

I do not have the SGX instruction itself both in CPU-Z and in the device manager in the software components in windows, but on the official Intel website, there is information that the processor supports SGX, but with Intel ME, downloading which - nothing has changed.
Characteristics of the computer:

| Component | Model |
| --- | --- |
| Processor | Intel Core i5 10400F |
| Motherboard | MSI B560M PRO-VDH |
| Video card | Geforce RTX 3060 |
| RAM | 16 GB |

The system is 64-bit

Comment: This isn't really about Ubuntu in my opinion. Have you accessed bios and checked what settings is available there? The [manual for your motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B560M-PRO-VDH/support#manual) has information about accessing bios.

Comment: Yea, i checked BIOS for 3 times. But maybe my system is not support Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: Can't see why not having SGX should stop you from using Ubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1454435/does-ubuntu-use-intel-sgx

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem. If you have only this warning(it is not an error), you can just start 'try ubuntu ( with safe graphics )' and then just wait for 1-2 minutes. After that installation will begin.
So you just need to wait for some time XD